# How to match one and/or more than one 0s in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm using Oracle 11g, I need help trying to figure out how to match a string of any length of 0s. But it should contain only 0s.

```
i.e.
0 - Valid
00 - Valid
0000 - Valid
0010000 - Invalid
000000000- Valid
```

Been trying to find some help on this, but to no avail.

Comment: Convert the value to an integer and compare to 0?

Comment: That helps for 0s but wanted a more generic one that could cover 1s 2s etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you can use [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_regexp.htm#i1007663) in your query, like so:

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(zeroes, '^0+$')
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. Have to wait 11 mins to accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the column only has numbers, then you might want to try and `CAST` it to an `INT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE CAST(YourColumn AS INT) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Check that the string contains any character, and after removing all zeroes contains no characters:

```
where length(field) > 0 and length(replace(field, '0', '')) = 0
```

If the value can never be an empty string, you can skip the first test:

```
where length(replace(field, '0', '')) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking that a field only contains characters from a limited subset can be done using the 'translate' function.

Example:

```
select t.FIELD
from   TABLE t
where  coalesce(length(translate(t.FIELD, 'x0', 'x')), 0) = 0
```

The translate in this case replaces 'x' by 'x' (does nothing with the 'x') and removes all other characters listed, in this case '0'. The result may be null, so a coalesce (ANSI variant of nvl) is needed.

This example can be extended to wider use, for example to list all fields that have non-numeric characters:

```
select t.FIELD
from   TABLE t
where  coalesce(length(translate(t.FIELD, 'x0123456789', 'x')), 0) != 0
```